# How to Downgrade/Upgrade multiple columns in multiple tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-migrations

I am able to Upgrade/downgrade recent changes in my database by using below commands

For Upgrade : In Package Manager Console used below command

```
pm > Add-Migration <Column Name>
```

For Downgrade : In Package Manager Console used below command

```
pm > Update-Database –TargetMigration:"ColumnName"
```

Can any one help how to Upgrade/Downgrade multiple columns in multiple tables.

Comment: What do you mean by upgrade multiple columns in multiple tables?

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka - here upgrade means update and downgrade means delete (selected columns) - Thanks for your quick question

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make multiple changes to multiple changes, just create a single migration step that includes it all.

1. Add the new properties that will generate the new columns to your entity classes.
2. Run `add-migration BunchOfColumns`

Looking at the `BunchOfColumns` migration step you should see code to add all the new columns to the classes. To downgrade, just migrate with `BunchOfColumns` as the target migration.